# authorize camera test in integration testing

Tags: flutter, integration-testing

I am writing integration tests for Flutter App. The app let's users to take video. When writing test, how can I allow camera permission for my app inside the script for integration testing when the permission dialog appears?

Answer (score 3):

With new integration_test package, you can grant permission in android inside `test_driver/integration_test.dart`:

```
// this permission grant workaround works only for android for now
Future<void> main() async {
  final Map<String, String> envVars = Platform.environment;
  final String adbPath =
      envVars['ANDROID_SDK_ROOT']! + '/platform-tools/adb.exe';
  await Process.run(adbPath, [
    'shell',
    'pm',
    'grant',
    'com.app.name',
    'android.permission.CAMERA'
  ]);
  await Process.run(adbPath, [
    'shell',
    'pm',
    'grant',
    'com.app.name',
    'android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO'
  ]);
  await integrationDriver();
}
```

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting `ProcessException: Permission denied` when trying this method?

Comment: are you using windows? if not you need to use just adb instead of adb.exe in linux/mac

Comment: No, macOS ... I've given up, lol

Comment: I think you have some problems in currently running user in your shell/cmd. Maybe you will find you answer there